# Calculate the average for the last 30 days excluding today. DAX

Tags: dax

I would like to calculate the average revenue for the last 30 days (not including today)
I tried the following formula but the amount calculated is incorrect:

```
CALCULATE(
           AVERAGE(table[Revenue]),
           FILTER(table,DATEADD(table[date],-30,DAY))
    )
```

How can I exclude today in the average?
If i wanted to compare that result with the 30 days before that (i.e between -30 days and -60days) should i use datesinperiod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DATESBETWEEN` function is the most intuitive to me.

```
Previous30DayAverage =
VAR CurrentDate = LASTDATE(table[date]) --Or TODAY() or whatever you choose
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE(table[Revenue]),
    DATESBETWEEN(table[date], CurrentDate - 30, CurrentDate - 1)
)
```

I think you can see how to tweak this for -30 to -60 days.